identifying relay model by rebound timing/signature?
Is it possible to create software that analyses the wave form from the rebounding to determine what model relay I'm dealing with? One model has an easily recognizable general pattern of short spikes followed by a large one, repeated either twice or three times.

The biggest problem is that the spikes merge with the waveform creating inconsistencies on how to define the pattern. Here for example with the same model but 2 different relays you get a third "square wave" that doesn't merge into the larger part of the wave. So I guess what i'm really looking at is how to make my rebounds consistent, is it possible to stop the spikes from merging like in the first image? Is there any better way to identify the different models?


No it isn't possible since relay characteristics depend on coil voltage and contact load etc. But also on the nature of what's connected to the contacts: AC supply, DC supply, signals etc etc.

@Lundin but I do have a consistent setup such as voltage, signal generator frequency , etc when I test these relays, if that's what you mean. The model above does appear to produce the same shape in 3 different relays. The first spike will appear in different relays within 0.5ms of each other, which is how I initially used to identify 2 different models but as I expanded to other ones they were overlapping

Yeah well most relays are of very similar design so why would any two of them bounce that much differently? I also recon that coil temperature will have quite some impact, so depending on how long you run it, tests might get ever so slightly different. And then relay mechanical aging... welding phenomenon over time. Etc etc.

@Lundin the different models I have do bounce differently though. It's just complicated that I have that problem I described originally where the spikes would merge into one big square wave and it's hard to identify that

of course it is possible ... use AI ... expect to spend lots of time and money to train the model

What are your two (or more?) relays that you are trying to discriminate? If you're trying to determine if you have a SSR vs and EM, the testing is trivial. If the two relays are of the same type but have vastly different characteristics, the testing is not trivial but achievable. If the relays are similar, any testing will be dubious. It might be useful to explain why you want to do this.

Maybe use a microphone to listen to the mechanical operation?

Or simply use already available products used for identifying components optically. AOI is standard procedure among professional assembly contractors. Why can't it be used here? Too simple, too reliable?

How many models you want to differentiate? And why? Do you want to do it in-circuit in the end product - and if so what would be the use of that? Or on the production line? Or in parts receiving process?
To me  the two waveforms you show look almost identical. You could also show the waveforms from another relay. It probably takes a couple minutes in Mathematica to convert the plot images to raw data, run some filter on it, and give the verdict. But you'd really want to do it yourself.
The current waveform through the coil must be controlled to be perfectly repeatable. That's done by generating a reference waveform - whether with a DAC or a simple analog circuit - then using that to control a current source. That will ensure that relay temperature won't affect the force imparted on the armature, at least not in the "first order".
If you were particularly fancy you could control the position of the armature in a closed loop by driving a high frequency test signal through the coil and estimating its inductance or the parasitic capacitance between the contacts and the core. The coil impedance and core-to-armature capacitance will vary with armature position. How well that works depends on the relay and level of perseverance, but in general you should be able to e.g. servo the armature half-way between the motion end points and keep it there indefinitely. That way you could control the armature velocity exactly. Or you could just try to get the waveforms at a couple of different current levels.
It is OK to drive the coil with several times the rated current for a very short time. What you can do, then, is to measure the saturation flux of the core. This may be quite model-dependent, since it depends on the geometry and material of the core, and on the geometry of the winding wire volume. To do that, pulse steeper and steeper current ramps in a closed loop current control. Eventually, the voltage will drop precipitously during the ramp when the magnetic circuit becomes saturated and the coil turns into an air solenoid. When that happens you can also estimate the number of turns, and thus amp-turns - a measure of the field strength. The data acquisition is a bit tricky of course.
You can also measure the static coil inductance. It varies between the relay models and if you're lucky may be a much better way to recognize the relay models, or at least add to other data.
So, there are many interesting ways of doing it. If I was making some general-purpose "spot the fakes" relay inspection system, I'd definitely implement all of those methods to generate an overall signature, extract some parameters of the signature, then use statistical methods to group the signatures according to model.
